# How to declare a variable for inner function in react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

when i try to use variable in my class function getting this error
`Cannot read property 'zoomInIndex' of undefined`

it is working fine if i have one function, can some one help me out how to use the variable in inner function or how to bind the inner function context?

```js
class MyContainer extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.testClick = this.testClick.bind(this);
        this.zoomClick = this.zoomClick.bind(this);
        this.testVarible= "this is a test";
    }

    zoomClick(inout) {
    return function(e) {
         console.log(this.testVarible); // this is not working 
      }
    }
    
    
    testClick(){
       console.log(this.testVarible);
    }
    
    
}
```

if i use fat arrow functions it is working fine

```
zoomClick = inout => e => {
    console.log(this.testVarible);
}
```

but i don't want to use fat arrow functions in react components since i ran into a lot of issues with my webpack configuration.

so my question is how to use the variable in inner function or how to bind the inner function context with out fat arrow syntax?

Comment: You don't need to `.bind` `zoomClick` if you are not passing the function elsewhere. Only bind functions if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `bind` the `function` returning from the `zoomClick()`:

```
zoomClick(inout) {
    return function(e) {
        console.log(this.testVarible); // this is not working
    }.bind(this); // <-- bind(this)
}
```

The anonymous `function` which was returned had no context of `this` and thus it was giving the error. Because `zoomClick` is already bound in the constructor, you just need to `bind` the `function(e) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You can bind it to the class context one of two ways:

`returnFunction = returnFunction.bind(this);` or `function() {}.bind(this)`.

```js
class MyContainer extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.testClick = this.testClick.bind(this);
        this.zoomClick = this.zoomClick.bind(this);
        this.testVarible = "this is a test";
    }

    zoomClick(inout) {
      let returnFunction = function(e) {
        console.log(this.testVarible);
        return this.testVarible;
      };
      returnFunction = returnFunction.bind(this);
      return returnFunction;
    }
    
    
    testClick(){
       console.log(this.testVarible);
    }
    
    render() {
      return (
        <div>{this.zoomClick(false)(false)}</div>
      );
    }
    
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyContainer/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> i don't want to use fat arrow functions in react components since i ran into a lot of issues with my webpack configuration

I'm guessing you tried to use class fields with the Babel plugin and that caused you some grief.

It's OK to use the traditional method of binding in the constructor *and* use arrow functions elsewhere in the code without running into those problems.

```js
class MyContainer extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.zoomClick = this.zoomClick.bind(this);
    this.testVarible = "this is a test";
  }

  zoomClick() {
    return (e) => {
      console.log(this.testVarible);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <Button handleClick={this.zoomClick} />
  }

}

function Button({ handleClick }) {
  return <button onClick={handleClick()}>Click</button>
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyContainer /> ,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: `.bind`ing `zoomClick` in the constructor is not even necessary in this case.